# mysql not starting in wmp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

In my pc
wamp was working fine 
now it stopped working Apache is starting and working 
my sql not working fine i re-installed wamp more than two times
  120601 15:54:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

```
120601 15:54:11 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120601 15:54:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
120601 15:54:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120601 15:54:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120601 15:54:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120601 15:54:12 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120601 15:54:13  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120601 15:54:14 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 33268580
120601 15:54:14 [ERROR] Binlog has bad magic number;  It's not a binary log file that can be used by this version of MySQL
120601 15:54:14 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
120601 15:54:14 [ERROR] Aborting

120601 15:54:14  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120601 15:54:14  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 33268580
120601 15:54:14 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

that is mysql error log

Comment: Not programming, it's system administration.

Answer (score 4):

You need to:

1. Stop mysql
2. Delete the log files like ib_logfile0...
3. Start mysql

Comment: Stop it with wamp menu. But I was some mistake. You do not need stop the service, because the service is not running. Ignore the first step!

Comment: Specifically, the log files that need to be deleted are:
ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 (and ib_logfile2, ib_logfile3, etc)
ib_data1, mysql-bin.0000001 (and mysql-bin.000002, mysql-bin.000003, etc), mysql-bin.index.  For me, these files were in the mysql\mysql5.6.12\data folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows and skype aswell, then quite skype first then start you services in wamp,

skype has conflicts with wamp

Comment: Skype only conflicts with apache, because skype uses the port 80 and 443 default. You can uncheck it in the settings, then you can start your webserver.

Comment: upvoted your answer, i knew it uses port 80, but i did not know that this only create problem for apache, 


but if its create problem for apache then how will other services like mysql run properly ? please elaborate ,...

Comment: Apache and web servers are listening on ports 80 and 443, but mysql is listening on port 3306 by default. So, if skype is sitting on port 80, port 3306 is free for use to mysql.

Comment: i fixed that before skype conflict but it was working

Comment: let me know any other conflict with wamp